# Parse SDK - Calling "fetch()" in a loop takes a lot of time to execute

Tags: php, parse-platform

I'm using the Parse PHP SDK for my project and I'm facing a little problem.

Here is my code until now :

```
// Fetch Videos
$fetch_videos_query = new Parse\ParseQuery("Video");
$video_results = null;

$fetch_videos_query->select("id", "author", "videoFile");
$fetch_videos_query->descending("createdAt");
$fetch_videos_query->includeKey("author");

$video_results = $fetch_videos_query->find();

if($video_results != null)
{  
    for($q1 = 0; $q1 < count($video_results); $q1++)
    {
        $video      = $video_results[$q1];
        $video_url  = $video->get("videoFile")->getUrl();
    }
}
```

I just want to list the data of my Video class into my web page. With this code, I get the following error :

> ParseObject has no data for this key. Call fetch() to get the data.

Ok, if I do that :

```
$video->fetch();
```

After this line :

```
$video = $video_results[$q1];
```

... it works but it takes a LOT OF time to load my page (something like 10 seconds) ...

How can I fix that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is

```
$fetch_videos_query->select("id", "author", "videoFile");
```

Because you're telling the query to return limited data. Include all the keys you need in this line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But what do you mean? Should I just remove this line?

Comment: You can, it is the reason you need to fetch (and a synchronous fetch in a loop is a very bad idea).

Comment: Perfect! That's it. Thank you very much. I thought it was better to fetch only the columns I need here (just like what I would do with MySQL).

Removing this line fixed my problem :-) !